# Oracle log miner permission: which permission authorize user to use logMiner as scheduled JOB?

Tags: oracle, log

I'm trying to config user to run logMiner from scheduled job periodly.

my user called admin
I've grant the admin user the following:

```
 grant select on v_$database to admin
 grant execute on DBMS_LOGMNR to admin
 grant select on v_$logmnr_contents to admin
```

but still, when I'm trying to select from v$logmnr_contents I get - ORA-01031 insufficient privileges.

for testing I'm running the following script:

```
create or replace procedure Test_LogMiner AS
first_scn NUMBER(8);
last_scn NUMBER(8);
log_count NUMBER(8); 
BEGIN
  Select current_scn into last_scn from V$DATABASE;
  --Select max(mined_scn) into first_scn from my_table;
  first_scn := last_scn-100;
  DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(startScn=>first_scn, endScn=>last_scn,
     options=>DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG+DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE);
  WRITE_LOG('LOG_DIR', 'After START_LOGMNR');
  -- get error on this select - ORA-01031 insufficient privileges-- 
  select count(*) into log_count from v$logmnr_contents;
  WRITE_LOG('LOG_DIR', 'select count(*)='||log_count);
  DBMS_LOGMNR.END_LOGMNR();
  WRITE_LOG('LOG_DIR', 'After END_LOGMNR');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  WRITE_LOG('LOG_DIR', 'Error: '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

I can ran the same scenario, mean start logMiner and select from v$logmnr_contents, when it not run as procedure, from SQL developer as admin user (means: the create proc. removed and the rest code put in another `begin` / `end`)

It also runs when I run the proc from 'sys as dba' user.

My question is: What else should I grant in manner the procedure work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE` to be assigned to the user.

> You must have been granted the EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE role to use the LogMiner PL/SQL packages and to query the V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS view.

For details:[Using LogMiner to Analyze Redo Log Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/logminer.htm)